# How to execute raw sql query and use model objects in Flask with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I need to build a complex query and I prefer to use raw postgres. But the query returns a `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy` object and when I iterate through that each of those objects is a `sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy` object

```
search_term = "%{0}%".format(d)
items = db.engine.execute("SELECT inventory.id,inventory.location,inventory.amount,inventory.units, plant_material.variety FROM inventory LEFT JOIN plant_material ON inventory.plant_material_id = plant_material.id WHERE plant_material.variety ILIKE %s", (search_term))
```

This standard query returns my model object that I define in Marshmallow, `<class 'app.models.Inventory'>:`

```
Inventory.query.filter(Inventory.common_name.like(search_term)).limit(10)
```

How can I return the models.Inventory object and use raw sql?

If you are curious about my model definitions check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fogonthedowns/459ed6b36eee3d88c7cf)

Comment: you _could_ just use the query api :) `Session.query(Inventory).outerjoin(PlantMaterial, PlantMaterial.id == Inventory.plant_material_id).filter(PlantMaterial.variety.ilike(search_term)).all()` otherwise sorry don't know the answer, would like to know if there is a way. I guess you could iterate over the rows and initialize the objects yourself.

Comment: I have situations like this myself. What I end up doing is making a second query using the query api, with an `in_` based on the ids the first query returned... very inefficient. Would love to know if there is a better way, great question.

Comment: @lee Thanks. I ended up querying the API just after I posted this question. I'm still very curious because the API has natural limits.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/queryguide.html#selecting-orm-entities-and-attributes

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text, select
db.session.execute(select(ModelClass).from_statement(text("SELECT ..."))).scalars().all()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
query = db.engine.execute("SELECT inventory.id...")
for row in query:
    print(row['id'])
    ...
```